# django-phonenumber-field: get phone number field validation pattern

Tags: python, regex, django, phone-number, parsley.js

I am using `django-phonenumber-field` in a model. I would like parsley.js to validate the model form on the client side. However, I cannot find the regular expression used to validate the `PhoneNumberField` field on the server side.

I would really like to use the exact same expression if possible.

Here are my model and form:

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class CVApplication(Application):
    mobile_phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    [...]


@parsleyfy
class CVApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CVApplication
        fields = (
            'mobile_phone_number',
            [...]
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CVApplicationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['mobile_phone_number'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'data-parsley-pattern': '??????????'}
        )
        [...]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

django-phonenumber-field relies on python-phoneumbers to validate a phone number.

You may to be able to pick what you need out of here: https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/dev/python/phonenumbers/phonenumbermatcher.py

Comment: I used `_PATTERN` re.compile first argument without success in my `data-parsley-pattern` attribute. I ended up with something really simple: `'^\+([0-9]{,15})$'` because the server side validation is more strict. Not the better solution but I guess I would spend too much time on that to get an acceptable solution...